# Android ViewModel management in mvvm

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-databinding

I'm creating a sample app ([Last-Mvvm](https://github.com/stefanosiano/Last-Mvvm)) to learn (and possibly show) the usage of mvvm pattern, using [Android data binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html).

I have an activity with my ViewModel object inside. I have also a RecyclerView adapter, which contains an arraylist of items that are converted to another Viewmodel. I want to save the state of the list inside the adapter (for rotation changes).
So: where should I save it? inside the activity? Or in the viewModel of the activity? Or somewhere else?

Also, there is another thing that isn't really clear.
Is it fine to perform rest calls (through [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit)) or database calls directly from the viewModel (since i'd use interfaces), or would it be better to make an interface that the view (activity) implements and performs all the calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to explain

> **First**. So: where should I save it? inside the activity? Or in the viewModel of the activity? Or somewhere else?

and

> **Second**. Is it fine to perform rest calls (through Retrofit) or database calls directly from the viewModel (since i'd use interfaces), or would it be better to make an interface that the view (activity) implements and performs all the calls?

on example from [article](https://habrahabr.ru/post/258195/).

On the schema below you can see implementation of `OnClickListener` and `OnLongClickListener` for `RecyclerView` item.
[image: Schema]

- doted lines is a links
- solid lines is a method calls

#### How it works

1. ViewHolderWrapper works as `ClickListener` for root view of `ViewHolder`. Depending on implementation `ViewHolderWrapper` can be proxy for `HolderClickObservable` or depending on [`SelectionHelper`](https://github.com/bejibx/android-recyclerview-example/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/bejibx/android/recyclerview/selection/SelectionHelper.java), `ViewHolderWrapper` can manually highlight selected item.
2. `SelectionHelper` is responsible for saving selection state and notify `SelectionObserver` about changes.
3. Listener (Adapter in this case) is responsible for highlighting of selected items and for updates.

#### Summarizing

**First**. You can restore adapter state via activity with methods `onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

**Second**. You need to create lightweight ViewHolder which only responsible for binding data to view. Actions can be performed at adapter or activity.

See also [example application](https://github.com/bejibx/android-recyclerview-example)

Comment: Thanks,  
I fixed the problem with saving and restoring state.  
I have another question: I have a RecyclerView adapter in my activity.   Should i keep it in my activity or should i move it into the ViewModel of the activity?

Comment: @StefanoSiano, please accept the answer, if it's helpfull for comunity

Comment: I think, `RecyclerViewAdapter` sould be placed in view model, becouse adapter responsible for view updates. Activity in this case works only as container and infrastructure for view model.